# How to enable action on UIImageview present on Scroll view

Tags: ios

Hi I have a Big Backgroung image , i added that image to BGimageview , then i added the BGImageView to ScrollView , Now i want to add another smallImageView on top og BGImageView that is also done. i had made some animation for that smallImageView on touching but it is not happening. please someone help me out.

Comment: How do you catch that touches?

Answer (score 0):

Image views don't receive touch events per default. You need to set userInteractionEnabled to YES.

Answer (score 0):

with the above answer given by @phix23 you need to use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` to handel the events on the imageviews just download the code from [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture)